# Error: Could not find method SubmitRegister(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

When I assign the android:onclick in XML to the function, I get this error:

Error: Could not find method SubmitRegister(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class

I checked my XML to see if there is a difference between the  names, but I can assure that the function name has been spelled right.

Function in MainActivity.java:

```
  public void SubmitRegister(View v) {

    Log.d("MyApp", "Register button clicked.");

}
```

XML Content_main.XML:

```
   <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Registreren"
        android:id="@+id/buttonRegister"
        android:layout_below="@+id/inputpassword2"
        android:onClick="SubmitRegister"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/inputpassword2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/inputpassword2"
        android:enabled="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Activity's onCreate method is inflating your xml.

I usually add the onClick Listener on the java code and not on the xml.
For example:

XML Content_main.xml :

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Registreren"
        android:id="@+id/buttonRegister"
        android:layout_below="@+id/inputpassword2"
        android:onClick="SubmitRegister"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/inputpassword2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/inputpassword2"
        android:enabled="true" />
```

JAVA MainActivity.java

```
Button btnRegister= (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);
btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.d("MyApp", "Register button clicked.");
            }
        });
```

Comment: This did not help me. I get bunch of illegal expression errors. I implemented  the OnClickListener.

Comment: Please see question.

Comment: ok, replace your commented onClickListener with the one I answered. 

And make sure that you activity_main.xml Layout file has an <include 'content_main'>